# Multiple dropdown toggle with data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, custom-data-attribute

I have a code(snippet below) but I can't figure out why does when clicking on the button, it shows menu only for the first dropdown. When clicking on the second button, it does nothing.

Any ideas?

Thank you

```js
document.querySelector("[data-toggle=dropdown]").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("data-target")).classList.toggle("d-block");
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  background: #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.d-block {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#test" class="btn btn-success">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="test" class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a></div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#test1" class="btn btn-success">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="test1" class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution, as for **why** your code didn't work, you were targeting a **single** dom object by using `querySelector`, as that would grab the first dom object that satisfies the query requirements. Whereas **`querySelectorAll`** will grab all elements that meet the query requirements, hope this has helped to some degree.

### Edit

I've included the feature so that if you click on a drop down twice it'll hide the current drop down! :)

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle=dropdown]");
for (var i = 0, s = list.length; i< s; i ++) {
  var elm = list[i];
  elm.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // this for loop will hide previously clicked drop downs
    for (var j = 0, z = list.length; j < z; j++) { 
      if (list[j] != this) {
        var elm = document.querySelector(list[j].getAttribute("data-target"));
        var str = elm.className.replace("d-block");
        elm.className = str;
      }
    } // if you like, remove the above loop
    var obj = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("data-target"));
    if (obj.className.indexOf("d-block") > 0) { 
      var temp = obj.className.replace("d-block", "");
      obj.className = temp; 
    } else { obj.className += " d-block"; }
  });
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  background: #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.d-block {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#test" class="btn btn-success">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="test" class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a></div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#test1" class="btn btn-success">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="test1" class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need)

Comment: It's my pleasure! No problem at all! I'm always happy to help! I take it you're new to JavaScript? Don't worry, I'm intermediate level at best, I'm still learning! :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector()` will only return the first element found; from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> Returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors, or null if no matches are found.

I would try `document.querySelectorAll()` as it seems like it's what you want. From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time to understand the code.
When I understood the essence, I wrote a shorter code.
I find it easier to read.

```js
var dropBtns = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle=dropdown]")

dropBtns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const dropMenu = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling

    if (dropMenu.classList.contains('show')) { 
      dropMenu.classList.toggle('show')
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(item => item.classList.remove('show'))
      dropMenu.classList.add('show')
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  background: #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.d-block {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#test" class="btn btn-success">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="test" class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a></div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#test1" class="btn btn-success">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="test1" class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a><a class="dropdown-item">Item</a></div>
</div>
```